# Official Ubuntu derivatives link at FAQ is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

The link pointing to Ubuntu about derivatives page is broken.

Located at https://askubuntu.com/faq page

Paragraph:

We welcome questions about:

- Using and administering Ubuntu, including **[official Ubuntu derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/derivatives)**.

Comment: Good catch. Any idea where it *should* now point anyone?

Comment: this one? http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives

Comment: @fossfreedom Thanks, edited.

Comment: @WarrenHill I've just double-checked the FAQ and it's definitely going to the new URL. Without meaning to teach you to suck eggs, are you on the right page (the link in the question *is* still the old one) and have you refreshed recently? Might be a cached version.

Comment: @Oli This is still an issue, and before you ask, I'm *very* sure I'm not seeing a cached page. I'm a new user.

Comment: I can confirm that too.

Comment: The link is still broken.